# Auto complete in visual code for nodejs and nodejs modules

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

I am trying to set auto complete for nodejs in my vcode on my linux box. But it won't seem to work. I added reference on my ts files but still can get  it to work.

```
 ///reference path="/home/avlahop/dtyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node-0.11.d.ts" />
///reference path="/home/avlahop/dtyped/DefinitelyTyped/redis/redis.d.ts" />

http = require("http");
var redis = require("redis");
```

but when typing `http.` I don't get any suggestions. Is there any way to set it up?

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial? https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs

Comment: Good one. DIdn't know it. /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory when running tsd command

Comment: Works for me. did you install the npm module?

Comment: yes followed the tutorial, but didn't work. sudo npm install -g tsd. But tsd --help doesn't give me any response. tsd query node --action install also no result. npm uninstall tsd says no module tsd installed

Comment: weird. not sure what to suggest then.'